# How to handle when SSRS does not automatically update fields based on database query?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

So I am trying to change the number of fields in my dataset in SSRS and the refresh button is not picking up the added field from the SQL server. The query is definitely returning the correct data, as I have double checked in the server engine itself. Also, I have tried manually adding the field using the SSRS menu, but as soon as I execute it disappears.

Any suggestions or similar experiences?

Comment: Using 2005, I haven't had the problem but I use stored procedures exclusively.

Comment: This is in 2005, in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that SSRS was pointing to the wrong database, but SQL Server was not. Problem solved...

Comment: I hate SSRS so much I think i'll shit my pants in frustration if I continue to think about it.

Comment: @Pierreten ahahahahah how come you say that? what do you prefer instead of SSRS?